# Custom validation rule on html array causes set_value return null

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have this custom validation rule to verify money greater than zero.

```
public function greater_than_zero_money($value)
{
    $value = str_replace(',', '', $value);
    $value = str_replace('.', '', $value);

    if ( empty($value) || floatval($value) <= 0 ){

        $this->form_validation->set_message('greater_than_zero_money', 'The {field} field must be greater than zero.');

        return false;

    }
}
```

And I set the custom validation rule this way

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules ( "vl_expense[$k]" , 'Expense Value' , 'callback_greater_than_zero_money' );
```

And TRY to set the value back, when it's an error on form like that, but always return NULL altough the $_POST is set.

```
set_value("vl_expense[{$e['cd_type_expense']}]")==NULL
$_POST["vl_expense"][$e['cd_type_expense']]==LAST VALUE FROM FORM
```

If I change the validation rule for TRIM (or other built-in validation), I get the values.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules ( "vl_expense[$k]" , 'Expense Value' , 'trim' );
```

I also try to mix trim and callback_greater_than_zero_money, but no success.

*Please, ignore the fact that variables $k and $e are not mentioned here. The error is not related to theses variables.*

Another interesting fact is that, I have another field with custom validation which works, **but is not an array**.

Answer (score 0):

Your code was dropping out the bottom. You need to return the validated value...

```
public function greater_than_zero_money($value)
{
    $value = str_replace(',', '', $value);
    $value = str_replace('.', '', $value);

    if ( empty($value) || floatval($value) <= 0 ){

        $this->form_validation->set_message('greater_than_zero_money', 'The {field} field must be greater than zero.');

        return false;

    }

    return $value;

}
```